# Slow scrolling performance with 9 columns using react-virtualized

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-virtualized

I'm using react-virtualized in pair with material-ui table cells to create table with virtual scrolling, everything seems fine but i get occasional performance slowdown while traversing table in both up and down directions. I open a dev console and found some warnings there - numerous

> [Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took ~116ms

And

> [Violation] 'scroll' handler took ~150ms

messages.

```js
  const MyTable: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  
    //props, styles, table content fetching here
  
    const headerRenderer = () => {
        return (
            <MyHeaderCell
                styleClass={classes.headerCell}
                content={"Header"}
            />
        );
    };

    const cellRenderer = (rendererProps) => {
        return (
            <MyContentCell
                styleClass={classes.tableCell}
                rendererProps={rendererProps}
            />
        );
    };

    const renderContent = () => {
        return (
            <InfiniteLoader
                isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded}
                loadMoreRows={loadMoretableItems}
                rowCount={tableItemsQuantity}
            >
                {({ onRowsRendered}) => (
                    <AutoSizer>
                        {(sizerProps: IAutoSizerProps) => {
                            const { height, width } = sizerProps;
                            return (
                                <Table
                                    onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                                    width={width}
                                    height={height}
                                    rowHeight={rowHeight}
                                    rowCount={tableItems.length}
                                    rowGetter={getCurrentRow}
                                    overscanRowCount={5}
                                    headerHeight={rowHeight}
                                    rowClassName={classes.flexContainer}
                                    noRowsRenderer={noRowsRenderer}
                                >
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.id)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.prop1)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.prop2)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.prop3)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.prop4)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.prop5)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.prop6)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.prop7)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                    <Column
                                        dataKey={nameof<MyTableItem>((o) => o.prop8)}
                                        width={width}
                                        headerClassName={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        headerRenderer={headerRenderer}
                                        className={clsx(classes.header, classes.column)}
                                        cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
                                    />
                                </Table>
                            );
                        }}
                    </AutoSizer>
                )}
            </InfiniteLoader>
        );
    };

    return (
        <Grid item container direction={"column"} className={classes.root}>
            <h4>{Translate.getString("My Table Items")}</h4>
            <Grid item className={classes.tableContainer}>
                {renderContent}
                <LoaderBlock isLoading={showTableLoader}/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};

export { MyTable };
```

What can i do to improve performance of my table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in case if anyone wondering how to fix this, - reducing cell and header HTML nesting helped me a lot to reduce lagging while traversing table. 
Material UI components producing quite big elements tree -> react-virtualized has a hard time to render heavy components while popping elements, so you should keep it as simple as possible.